# Why not undefined expression is different from numerical underflow?

Tags: terminology, math, implementation, books, storage

Consider an architecture or programming language that uses $n$ bits for storing a floating point number in a particular format. Then each and every floating point number it can store should be in a given range, say $[lf, uf]$.

If there is a need to store any floating point number less than $lf$ then we generally treat such phenomenon as underflow. Consider the following from [Numerical Computation chapter of Deep Learning book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/numerical.html).

> One form of rounding error that is particularly devastating is
> underﬂow . Underﬂow occurs when numbers near zero are rounded to zero.
> Many functions behave qualitatively diﬀerently when their argument is
> zero rather than a small positive number. For example, we usually want
> to avoid **division by zero** (some software environments will raise
> exceptions when this occurs, others will return a result with a
> placeholder **not-a-number value**) or **taking the logarithm of zero**
> (this is usually treated as $-\infty$, which then becomes **not-a-number**
> if it is used for many further arithmetic operations).

You can observe that two examples has been given while explaining underflow: division by zero and logarithm of zero. If we treat mathematically, both are **undefined**. It should not be an issue of storage, especially underflow.

Is there any reason behind proving such examples, which are mathematically undefined, under the umbrella term **underflow** and using the term "not-a-number"?

Comment: Great question!  I'm a discrete guy, so I try to avoid floats, and am looking forward to an accepted answer.  (I noted recently how trivial any standard precision becomes for things like fractals:)  Excellent link—useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can be related to underflow. Mathematically, we do not expect facing with division by zero when we have an expression $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ when $\varepsilon > 0$. However, in numerical softwares, it can happen if $\varepsilon < lf$.

Moreover, you can think about the same scenario for taking the logarithm of zero.

Answer (score 0):

According to IEEE Standard, a processor must set exception flags if any of the following conditions arise when performing operations: underflow, overflow, divide by zero, inexact, invalid. Therefore, there is a special numeric binary representation for these conditions which is defined as the value NaN in IEEE single-precision and double-precision format.